# Formula to grab value from a cell and use that to refer to a cell in another spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, cell, formula, excel-indirect

I need help creating a formula in a cell in a spreadsheet that would allow me to grab a value from another cell and use that value to refer to yet another cell in another sheet.

For example, in a cell that returns a student's class grade (a progress report sheet) I have the cell refer to my master grade sheet (eg. the progress report sheet's cell would be:   `=mastersheet!E[grab value in cell A1 of current sheet])`

What formula do I use to grab a cell's value and use it to define/refer to another cell?

Comment: Please help us to help you...please can you be more specific about the quesy.....have you tried the = importrange("spreadsheetkey","Range") formula in Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of the student's progress report sheet http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/81c5d022-b7aa-45ec-ab0c-bd98699019a1/89953db4a12f93dfa597533d5cec08f6  and here is a link to a screenshot of the master gradesheet http://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/3593a50a-c243-4504-a781-569eb239a0f3/7e6b55f84f7d4dc355c315d852a49ac9  what i'm wanting to do is to have the individual's progress report pull their grade from the master by using the value in cell E1 of the progress report sheet to refer to the correct student's row in the master sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, if Sheet1 A1 contains `B2` then in Sheet1 `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&A1)` will return the contents of Sheet2!B2.

In Google Docs spreadsheet, if Sheet1 E1 contains `4` then in Sheet1 `=Indirect("Sheet2!E"&E1)` will return the contents of Sheet2 Cell E4.